# IIS 7.0 have some limit connection request per ip

Tags: iis-7

I'm using Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition in our company environment.
Does IIS 7.0 have some limit connection request per ip?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box.  You'll need a custom HTTP handler or third party module that will handle monitor and perform the limiting.

Comment: Don't forget that the HTTP 1.1 standard specifies that a client should have no more than 2(or 4?) connections open to the same server at a time. I believe that IE actually honors this. (or used to)

Answer (score 1):

It can.  If you use the Dynamic IP restriction module you can limit the number of requests per IP per time period.  By default the only limitations are the ones that TCP/IP has.

Answer (score 0):

No, but some application frameworks serialize based on a cookie, which can appear to behave in the same way (except it's one per unique browser instance, rather than per IP).

For example, if ASP sessions are enabled, you may find requests serialized from the same browser client.